# Какие репозитории для Oracle Linux посоветуете, чтобы поставить php-mbstring и php-bcmath?

Tags: linux, redhat, centos7

Здравствуйте.

Для установки приложения на Oracle Linux 7.4 необходимы php-mbstring и php-bcmath

список репозиториев, которые есть

```
Loaded plugins: replace, ulninfo
repo id                                     repo name                                                                                        status
*epel/x86_64                                Extra Packages for Enterprise Linux 7 - x86_64                                                         11,948
ol7_UEKR4/x86_64                            Latest Unbreakable Enterprise Kernel Release 4 for Oracle Linux 7Server (x86_64)                       335+93
ol7_latest/x86_64                           Oracle Linux 7Server Latest (x86_64)                                                             17,653+5,136
zabbix/x86_64                               Zabbix Official Repository - x86_64                                                                        28
zabbix-non-supported/x86_64                 Zabbix Official Repository non-supported - x86_64
```

Какие репозитории для Oracle Linux посоветуете, чтобы поставить php-mbstring и php-bcmath?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

На все случае жизни, там любые батарейки.

https://rpmfusion.org/

пс в тегах RHL и CentOS, Oracle Linux основан на базе RHL, думаю не будет проблем.